# Is there a GDAL build available for Python 3.2 Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdal

I am interested in using GDAL for Python 3.2 Windows 7 64 bit.  I have not come across a suitable build.  If there is not a build available, how would I go about building GDAL myself for Python 3.2 Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is  and I'm using it :)

I know this post is a bit old but I hope this link is useful:

You can download it from Tamas Szekeres' [excellent repository](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) of precompiled binaries.  You'll need to browse a bit to identify the version you want depending on your version of MSVC (he compiles against 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010!).